# Is there a gender neutral phrase or expression to replace "old woman"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, pejorative-language

There are people who behave like the stereotypical old woman who frets over the smallest concern and is constantly cautioning others about physical dangers.  Such people can be either sex and barely middle-aged.

They always click on buy travel insurance when booking an airticket, they regard a ladder as akin to a 5.14 climb.  They are obsessed with germs. They are uncomfortable beyond the confines of a 4- star hotel.  They set up absurd procedures "in case anything happens" (I don't mean writing a will).  They cancel their indoor tennis game if there is one inch of snow on the ground.  The males make an enormous deal out of a broken leg.

Maybe they are mainly women, and maybe they are middle-aged or older, but is there another term (phrase, expression or word), one that is gender neutral?

They can be very nice people, but they are dismissable as "old women".  Even I do it in my mind (never out loud) and I don't like that in myself.

**There are/have been many great old women — Jane Goodall, for example, and Golda Meir and many others** — and there will be more as people retain physical and mental strength deeper into old age.  But there will still be a phrase needed for the "timid, over-cautious, dithery, person whose overriding goal is safety.  I'd like a gentle term that could be used with humor but that will rachet down the twittering and fluttering whenever a competent person starts to do something that makes them nervous.

Comment: I think it would be old person

Comment: "The males make an enormous deal out of a broken leg." - you mean that they cancel their tennis game? *Again*?

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt They cancel their ski trip, even though their wife is perfectly able to ski and they could après ski all day.  It's the airport ... too hard to navigate the airport. Wah!

Comment: You're asking for a gentle and respectful term but there's nothing in your post that suggest you share some sympathy for them, it's quite a scathing report of people who are no longer in their prime, and a very short-sighted one, too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Most of these people are younger than I am by 15 to 20 years, so no, I don't have much sympathy for a middle-aged person in good health  who thinks hanging a bird feeder is a dangerous occupation.

Comment: Well I'm fifty years old, and I don't consider myself to be an old woman, thank you very much! ;) How old are you, 19? :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Nor did I when I was your age, nor do I now. But many people do behave like a stereotypical old woman, and I'd like a different word to describe these ... worrywarts...is what I am tending towards.

Comment: I am not sure I entirely accept your understanding of what constitutes an *old woman*. (I am incidentally old enough long to predate political correctness - although I do see the point of it). So I lived a good part of my life with the idea of what constitutes *an old woman*. In Britain, it was nearly always directed at a male, but one who was the things you mention, but also one who just refused to see sense and reason, trotting out the same hackneyed arguments *ad infinitum*. I keep wanting to call Nigel Farage *an old woman*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to characterize their fears as excessively focused on unlikely issues, you could call them a ***[worrywart](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worrywart)***:

> : a person who worries too much or who worries about things that are not important <sub>*[m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worrywart)*</sub>

Comment: Really good.  Can be said dismissively, but with humor.

Comment: Definitely gender-neutral.

Answer (score 9):

My generation tends to call this type of person an **old fogey** (instead of old man or old woman), plural *old fogeys*.

I can't do better than Word-Detective.com, so here's a post from that site that explains perfectly:

> "Fogey," of course, is, as the Oxford English Dictionary puts it so
>   well, "a disrespectful appellation for a man advanced in life,
>   especially one with antiquated notions; an old-fashioned fellow." The
>   word (also spelled "fogy," by the way) is probably Scottish in origin,
>   but its ultimate roots are a bit uncertain. It's possible that "fogey"
>   is based on an antiquated sense of "foggy," which meant
>   "moss-covered," but my favorite theory traces it to the Scottish word
>   "foggie," meaning a kind of brown bumblebee.
>
> "Fogey" is almost always preceded by the slightly redundant "old," but
>   there are, indeed, "young fogeys." The term is most often used to
>   refer to a group of young but conservative writers and novelists in
>   England who came to prominence in the early 1980s. The novelist and
>   critic A.N. Wilson is probably the "young fogey" most widely known to
>   Americans.
>
> Maybe it's my own age showing, but the term "fogey" doesn't seem quite
>   as pejorative to me as it used to -- my sense is that it is getting
>   harder to pin down exactly where good taste leaves off and "fogeyness"
>   begins. I would like to think that one doesn't have to be an "old
>   fogey" or even a "young fogey" to object to "tabloid TV," "shock
>   radio" and the popular fascination with "supermodels" which seem to
>   have supplanted what was left of American culture, but I may be wrong.
>   Maybe I'm a some sort of fogey after all. There are worse fates.

http://www.word-detective.com/back-b.html

Comment: This a great deal of what I want....it doesn't have the element of physical timidity, not only for oneself but for everyone else....(the ladder as a technical climb) ,but it has the great virtue that I could get away with calling someone an old fogey if I did it with good humor.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how much you are wanting to point and make fun.

**Over-anxious** perhaps?

*The over-anxious always click on "buy travel insurance" when booking a ticket.*

Comment: Good!  I don't want to ridicule, I want them to stop assuming I will kill myself just because they would if they did what I am doing.

Answer (score 2):

You could refer to these apprehensive persons as **nervous Nellies** (or the singular *nervous Nelly*), Merriam-Webster defines the term

> plural **[nervous Nellies](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nervous%20Nellie)**
>
> a timid or worrisome person
> — *many new parents are nervous Nellies when it comes to the health of their babies*

Comment: Apt.  I think some of them never get over the motherhood phase of their lives.

Answer (score 1):

**finicky** is kinder and gentler, I think.

excessively particular or fastidious; difficult to please; fussy.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/finicky?s=t

Comment: +1 but maybe too kind.  Finiky and dithering are indeed traits of old women, but I am looking for something that brings out the idiotically wimpy aspect, but is not horribly rude.

Comment: @ab2: Oh, so, you mean, like, something ironic? (Since the sarcastic words are too harsh ... not subtle enough?)

Comment: Yes, a term one can say that can be either insulting or playful depending on tone.  Calling someone an old woman is always insulting.  Sad, but true.

Comment: @ab2: .... Cleopatra?